# why won't mountNode is react work?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code, which I have put together from looking at a tutorial here: 
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/how-to-use-facebooks-react-library-to-build-UIs/

```
<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM
*/
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Greetings, Human {this.props.name} </h1>
            <p>
              Would you like to play a game?<br />
              How about a nice game of
              <a href="http://nsa.gov"> Chess</a>?
            </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(
  HelloMessage(),
  document.getElementById('rcomponent')
);
```

When I change the last part to:

```
React.renderComponent(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

I get this error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mountNode is not defined
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening? I have looked at at least 5 other examples and the syntax and layout is the same in all of them so I have no idea what's going wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

use a valid node instead of `mountNode` :

insert this line after the body tag

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

then replace

```
document.getElementById('example')
```

instead of mountNode

```
React.renderComponent(<HelloMessage name="John" />, document.getElementById('example'));
```